# Need to merge multiple MSG files into PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, merge

I have about 900 .msg (email) files. I need to convert them all to 1 single PDF file. How can one do this using Adobe Acrobat, or some other software?

Sorry if this is the wrong place to post this, but regrettably there is no "Adobe" Stack Exchange.

Comment: Sounds more like a question to superuser. But you will first print all those emails.

Comment: Physically print? Or print to PDF?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is really a *design* question. The .msg files would need to either be converted to something more standard or, as eluded to.. print to PDF (which would be a pain). Most PDF apps probably aren't going to work with .msg files directly... but then.. I've never tried anything with an .msg file either. If you have Acrobat.. just try dragging a .msg file to the Acrobat icon and see if it converts.